# How Windows Forms usage can be affected by the advent of Windows 8?

Tags: .net, winforms

I find that, Windows 8 will be highly HTML5 + Javascript based Metro Application oriented platform and regular desktop based application (Windows Form) can be run in Chrome mode which will be kind of demotivating and discouraging for the users. I cant figure out what can be the future of Windows Forms.
Thanks.

Comment: Look at how many organisations still use XP when Vista and Seven have been out for years.  Just becuae Win 8 doesn't promote the use of WinForms, it definitely doesn't mean they will die overnight, or even in a few years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you look back to the days of MFC, ActiveX, WinForms, WPF. That will gives you some ideas on the future.

Also you can see how major vendors such as Telerik, Infragistics, and DevExpress respond.

It is impossible to answer your question, as only Microsoft has the answer or even they don't know it clearly.